# How to remove upper and lower bounds with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I have a dataframe with 2 important columns.One of these important columns is the "Price" column and the other is the "Quantity" column.

My dataframe;

| Price | Quantity | Total Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 500 | 4000 |
| 6 | 100 | 4000 |
| 7 | 400 | 4000 |
| 8 | 200 | 4000 |
| 9 | 200 | 4000 |
| 10 | 800 | 4000 |
| 10 | 200 | 4000 |
| 10 | 300 | 4000 |
| 10 | 300 | 4000 |
| 11 | 300 | 4000 |
| 12 | 300 | 4000 |
| 12 | 100 | 4000 |
| 13 | 200 | 4000 |
| 14 | 100 | 4000 |

My code;

```
#The type of 2 columns is set to float and the price column is divided by 100
data_state['Price'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
data_state['Quantity'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
data_state['Price'] = data_state['Price'] /  100 

#price and quantity sorting smallest to largest
data_state = data_state.sort_values(['Price', 'Quantity'], ascending=(True, True))

#Getting the sum of the quantity column
data_state['Total Quantity'] = data_state['Quantity'].sum()

#The total quantity column is multiplied by the value of "0.15" and the part to be subtracted from the total is found.
data_state['Total Quantity Bounds'] = data_state['Total Quantity'] * 0.15

#At this stage, I need to decrease the value that I found from the smallest to the largest, from the top and bottom of the ordered quantity column. I mean; for the quantity which are at the upper and lower bounds, only the part of Quantity which falls in central 70% are included in the calculation.
```

#**The top and the bottom 15% of the "Total Quantity"** are detected as outliers and **removed from the "Quantity"**

İn this dataframe Lower Bounds;

Lower Bounds: 4000 * 0.15 = 600 Quantity

İn this dataframe Upper Bounds;

Upper Bounds: 4000 * 0.15 = 600 Quantity

**My expected output;**

| Price | Quantity | New Total Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 2800 |
| 6 | 0 | 2800 |
| 7 | 400 | 2800 |
| 8 | 200 | 2800 |
| 9 | 200 | 2800 |
| 10 | 800 | 2800 |
| 10 | 200 | 2800 |
| 10 | 300 | 2800 |
| 10 | 300 | 2800 |
| 11 | 300 | 2800 |
| 12 | **100** | 2800 |
| 12 | 0 | 2800 |
| 13 | 0 | 2800 |
| 14 | 0 | 2800 |

As you can see above, Numbers close to the "quantity" number from upper and lower in the quantity column corresponding to the number 600 (4000 * 0.15).
In particular, I reduced the previously **300 figure, which corresponds to the price 12, to 100.**

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to compute the cumulated sum on the forward and reverse array combined with `clip`:

```
# get first value in Total Quantity column and multiply by desired factor
qty = df['Total Quantity'].iat[0]*0.15

# update Total Quantity column
df['Total Quantity'] -= 2*qty

## trim top

# compute the cumulated quantity and identify the value strictly lower than qty
cs = df['Quantity'].cumsum()
m = cs.lt(qty)

# select those rows and the one after (shift)
# remove the qty from the cumulated sum clipping negative values to zero
# and update the dataframe
df.loc[m|m.shift(), 'Quantity'] = cs.loc[m|m.shift()].sub(qty).clip(0)


## trim bottom
# identical to above but on the reversed [::-1] array

cs = df['Quantity'][::-1].cumsum()
m = cs.lt(qty)
df.loc[m|m.shift(), 'Quantity'] = cs.loc[m|m.shift()].sub(qty).clip(0)
```

output:

```
    Price  Quantity  Total Quantity
0       5         0          2800.0
1       6         0          2800.0
2       7       400          2800.0
3       8       200          2800.0
4       9       200          2800.0
5      10       800          2800.0
6      10       200          2800.0
7      10       300          2800.0
8      10       300          2800.0
9      11       300          2800.0
10     12       100          2800.0
11     12         0          2800.0
12     13         0          2800.0
13     14         0          2800.0
```

Comment: what a great answer. That's all I wanted to do. Can you explain in detail what you are doing in the code line by line? I'm asking to find out. For example iat[0] or df.loc[m|m.shift(), 'Quantity'] could you explain these parts?

Comment: @Bianconera I added details

Comment: Thank you. Finally, TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' when I multiply qty = df['Total Quantity'].iat[0]*0.15. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Do you maybe have strings? Check and convert to number if needed

Comment: data_state['Total Quantity'] = data_state['Quantity'].sum() ; when I try this and output via excel, it seems like 500100400xxxxxxxxxxxxx. Since it does not see quantities as numbers, it writes numbers side by side instead of adding.

Comment: Typical behavior of strings ;) do `data_state['Total Quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(data_state['Total Quantity'])`. If error check carefully the values.